# Polars Aggregate Multiple Rows into One Row

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a df created like this:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({'schema_name': ['test_schema', 'test_schema', 'test_schema_2'], 
                   'table_name': ['test_table', 'test_table','test_table_2'],
                   'column_name': ['test_column', 'test_column','test_column_2']})
```

| schema_name | table_name | column_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test_schema | test_table | test_column |
| test_schema | test_table | test_column_2 |
| test_schema_2 | test_table_2 | test_column |

I would like to use polars to aggregate the `column_name` field by `schema_name` and `table-name` so that multiple values from `column_name` are combined into one row. The target dataset is this:

| schema_name | table_name | column_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test_schema | test_table | test_column, test_column_2 |
| test_schema_2 | test_table_2 | test_column |

I can aggregate the values into a list with this:

```
df.groupby(['schema_name','table_name']).agg(pl.col('column_name').list().alias('column_list'))
```

How do I then convert the list field (`column_list`) into a comma separated string? With pandas, I would do something like this:

```
df['column_list_string'] = [','.join(map(str, l)) for l in df['column_list']]
```

However, I can't figure out how to use `.join()` in combination with polars `.agg()`.

Alternatively, how would I go straight from multiple rows to one row without using the list as an intermediate step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.str.concat()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.concat.html#polars-expr-str-concat)

```
>>> df.groupby(['schema_name','table_name']).agg(pl.col('column_name').str.concat(", "))
shape: (2, 3)
┌───────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ schema_name   | table_name   | column_name              │
│ ---           | ---          | ---                      │
│ str           | str          | str                      │
╞═══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ test_schema_2 | test_table_2 | test_column_2            │
├───────────────┼──────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│ test_schema   | test_table   | test_column, test_column │
└───────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```