What is the idiomatic way to aggregate into a list using Polars
This code works, but it is clunky and apply is deprecated anyway:

import polars as pl

# Sample data
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "group": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C"],
    "values": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})

# Apply a lambda function to group and collect values into a list
result = df.groupby("group").agg([
    pl.col("values").apply(lambda x: x.to_list()).alias("values_list")
])

print(result)

Code feels even worse if I use the suggested map_elements(lambda x:x.to_list():return_dtype=object).
I wish I could just do pl.col("values").list() or pl.col("values").collect_list() but neither of those are exist for polars = "^0.20.19" .
Questions:

Is this the idiomatic Polars way to do this? (equivalent to just using list in Pandas?
Or is there some better way?


Sort of like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75140280/polars-aggregate-multiple-rows-into-one-row but instead of ending up with a string, I want to keep the object list

Just .agg(pl.col("values")) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78102341/

never apply apply
